# GnuPG and cipher mode of operation

Tags: pgp

What cipher mode of operation does the GnuPG software use? And how I can change the mode? In `openssl`, I can explicit say "aes-256-ecb" or "aes-256-cbc".

Comment: well, you do NOT want ecb, so the other option is cbc ?

Comment: [GPG uses CFB](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42459/gnupg-inner-workings-encryption-scheme-mode-of-operation-ciphers), which AFAIK cannot be changed.

Comment: @RichieFrame I ask if I have option for choose mode of operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenPGP defines its [own variety of the CFB mode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-13.9); which is the only mode that can be used, there is no choice for other modes.

For `gpgsm` ("GnuPG for S/MIME"), other modes would be theoretically possible, but I could not find any hint in the documentation that other modes can actually be chosen.

Comment: Actually, CFB mode is used in Integrity protected packets and OpenPGPCFB in non-integrity protected.