# What is the best command line option to use to encrypt files using GPG on Mac for personal upload to the cloud?

Tags: gnupg

I would like to use `gpg` on my Mac, which I currently have installed. I saw that a lot of options with the documentation on `gpg` are for sending and receiving files to someone else, which I am not trying to do. I am hoping to encrypt large files with at least a AES-256 method and am trying to upload them to the google drive or dropbox after (I have a fast upload connection). Does anyone have any idea what command would be used? It seems most commands require some notion of a private/public key and I am not sure if I need that if I don't intend on sending my files to another party. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By searching for "gnupg symmetric encryption", I found [this guide](https://www.tutonics.com/2012/11/gpg-encryption-guide-part-4-symmetric.html), which lists the steps and required options step-by-step.

## Symmetric vs. Asymmetric Cryptography

The very quick summary is that symmetric cryptography uses the same key for encryption and decryption, where asymmetric cryptography has a public key and a private key. The recipients public key is used to encrypt data, and the recipient uses their private key to decrypt.

GnuPG is designed primarily to work with asymmetric cryptography, which is why many of the options mention "recipients". Of course, you can also use GnuPG to encrypt files symmetrically as well.

## How can I encrypt a file symmetrically?

When you type in

```
gpg --version
```

then you will see the version number of your GnuPG installation, as well as the symmetric ciphers supported by your installation. It'll look somewhat like this:

```
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
    CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
```

You can now pick any of these ciphers, although `AES256` is a safe choice. If you are worried about modes, GnuPG uses their own [variant of the CFB-mode](https://superuser.com/a/969239), though this doesn't matter too much for this use case.

After you have picked a cipher, you can now begin encrypting your file:

```
gpg -c --cipher-algo AES256 -o myEncryptedFile.mp3.gpg myPlaintextFile.mp3
```

GnuPG will now ask you to enter and repeat a passphrase. Don't forget the passphrase, as you will not have *any* option to recover your data without it. Also, `.gpg` is not a standardized file extension or necessary. It just helps you remember that the file is encrypted.

The file can be decrypted simply by typing

```
gpg -d myEncryptedFile.mp3.gpg
```

## What about asymmetric cryptography?

You could also use asymmetric cryptography, and use your own public key as the recipient. This causes GnuPG to generate a random key for AES256, which may be more secure than a "rememberable" passphrase. This random key is then encrypted with your public key and can be decrypted with your private key.

The advantage of this approach is that you don't need to remember the key you used to encrypt the files. This may come in handy if you plan on storing those files for a long time and have a hard time remembering passwords.

The downside is that, if you lose your private key, your files are irrecoverably gone. You can of course mitigate this risk somewhat by copying your private key to multiple devices, making regular backups of it, etc.